# django admin custom template for model redirection

Tags: python, django, model, admin

A curious question
Suppose I have a module/app say Demo which contains a model say "anything". Now I registered this model to admin.py. 
Now when I log in to admin and see this model I see general update, delete option in admin template.

Is it possible that when I see this model in admin and click that model it redirects to another url that is of that module's url and it display in another template and I can show anything I like from view..

I am sorry if it is confusing. What I want is I want to show the admin's model property like update, add and delete in another custom template made by me and it should be redirected to url defined in the module's urls.py

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by extending your base get_urls() method [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites)